# Google Cloud Storage Java Client Pooling

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am working with GCS -

```
StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build()
                .getService();
```

My system is multithreaded. I would like to use the same Storage object to handle many concurrent requests (hundreds). How can I manage the connections, e.g pooling? 
Is the client (Storage object returning from the snippet above) thread safe?

I am using :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.61.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

EDIT:
Here is the answer I got from Google developers:

> 1. Normally you do not need to make any special arrangements regarding connection management. There is no capacity constraints of any kind on a Google side though.
> 2. The underlying libraries that the Java Storage is built on are thread-safe.

Comment: Based on the continued comments in the answer I deleted here, it seems there are too many open questions to give a reasonably-sized answer to everything.  For those who are curious what the Cloud Storage SDK actually does behind the scenes, you should examine the source code: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-storage

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson. I am familiar with the source code that you have referred to. I am either looking for a more complex code example or documentation relevant to my question.

Comment: Source code is actually in many ways better than documentation, because everything is right there.  Stack Overflow isn't an appropriate forum to ask for examples or external links.  If you have an observable problem using the APIs, that's something to discuss here.

Comment: Seems like the question is fine now. It was edited and now the question is very relevant. You can concise it to 'how to use this client in a multithreaded environment'. 
I do not see anything wrong here.

Comment: I have been using Stack Overflow for YEARS and links to specs & code snippets are very common :)
So I am still wondering - is the call to  
`storage.create(blobInfo, bytes);`
thread safe?